# Unable to resolve data for blob react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, blob, linkedin-api

Hi I am trying to integrate the react-native-linkedin library into my react native project.I am able to login successfully but I get the following warning.

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Unable to resolve data for blob: (null)
Error: Unable to resolve data for blob: (null)
    at createErrorFromErrorData (blob:http://localhost:8081/dcc710df-7404-48eb-87aa-84e591952a51:2038:17)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/dcc710df-7404-48eb-87aa-84e591952a51:1990:27
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (blob:http://localhost:8081/dcc710df-7404-48eb-87aa-84e591952a51:2432:18)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/dcc710df-7404-48eb-87aa-84e591952a51:2177:18
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://localhost:8081/dcc710df-7404-48eb-87aa-84e591952a51:2345:11)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/dcc710df-7404-48eb-87aa-84e591952a51:2176:14)
    at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:72:58
console.warn @ YellowBox.js:82
onUnhandled @ Promise.js:44
onUnhandled @ rejection-tracking.js:71
(anonymous) @ JSTimers.js:258
_callTimer @ JSTimers.js:154
callTimers @ JSTimers.js:407
__callFunction @ MessageQueue.js:353
(anonymous) @ MessageQueue.js:118
__guardSafe @ MessageQueue.js:316
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:117
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:72
```

I am testing my react native app on a iphone. 
Following is my code to get the user profile on successful login.

```
  async getUser({ access_token }) {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    const baseApi = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/";
    const qs = { format: "json" };
    const params = [
      "first-name",
      "last-name",
      "picture-urls::(original)",
      "headline",
      "email-address"
    ];

    const response = await fetch(
      `${baseApi}~:(${params.join(",")})?format=json`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        }
      }
    );
    const payload = response.json();
    this.setState({ ...payload, refreshing: false });
  }
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have React Native's remote debugging turned on. Verify that the issue occurs only with remote debugging turned on. If so, you'll need to override RN's polyfills with Chrome's native implementations. You've likely already done this for `XMLHttpRequest` in `App/index.js`, like so:

```
if (typeof GLOBAL !== 'undefined') {
  // Route network requests through Chrome's native XMLHttpRequest
  GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

  // Use native Blob for native XMLHttpRequest set above
  GLOBAL.Blob = GLOBAL.originalBlob || GLOBAL.Blob;

  // Use native FileReader to read native Blob set above
  GLOBAL.FileReader = GLOBAL.originalFileReader || GLOBAL.FileReader;
}
```